# Cuando escribo nodejs --version luego de actualizarlo, me devuelve la versión vieja

Tags: nodejs, npm

Instalé nodejs en mi PC con Ubuntu 22.04 usando el comando: `sudo apt install nodejs npm` y me instaló la versión 12.22.9, pero como quería tener una versión más nueva, instalé
`sudo npm install -g n`
con n instalé la versión 16.
Pero, cuando escribo `nodejs --version`, me devuelve la vieja versión 12.
¿Cómo corrijo este problema?

Comment: Yo no te aconsejo que te instales node con ``apt`` directamente porque instala unas 200 Mb de paquetes que en principio no se necesitan. Mi consejo es que vayas directamente a la [web de node](https://nodejs.org/) y ahí descargues los binarios de node y los instales directamente: instalará sólamente ``node``y ``npm``, con lo que el consumo de espacio será mucho menor, e instalarás sólamente los paquetes necesarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al final decidí desinstalar todo e instalar nodejs con nvm... Pero tu sugerencia me pareció muy buena para tener en cuenta... Como recién estoy empezando, trato de ir a lo más fácil...